# Cognos SQL WITH clause generating syntax error

Tags: sql, cognos

I have an SQL query I'm running in Cognos 11 and am trying to use a WITH clause but keep getting an error for incorrect syntax near "WITH".  I thought my org admins had disabled WITH but I have confirmed with them that it's enabled and I cannot figure out what is wrong with my syntax.  I've tried this in both Native SQL as well as Pass-through SQL.

I have this wrapped in a CASE that is otherwise working fine:

```
CASE 
WHEN SAPStreams.Stream_Type = 'INTELILINK' THEN (
    WITH IntelilinkValues AS (
    SELECT 
        LBD.Amount,
        LBD.Payment_Frequency,
        LBD.No_of_Periods
    FROM _SYS_BIC.LeasingRebooksDetails LBD 
    WHERE LBD.Contract_Number='D003498006')
)
ELSE NULL END
```

Pretty straight forward and I am more convinced there's something wrong with my org's implementation of Cognos than I am that the SQL is faulty.  Hoping for some help from this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a common table expression inside a query.  Even if I correct your CTE:

```
CASE 
WHEN SAPStreams.Stream_Type = 'INTELILINK' THEN (
    WITH IntelilinkValues (
        Amount,
        Frequency,
        Periods
    )
    AS (
    SELECT 
        LBD.Amount,
        LBD.Payment_Frequency,
        LBD.No_of_Periods
    FROM _SYS_BIC.LeasingRebooksDetails LBD 
    WHERE LBD.Contract_Number='D003498006'
    )
    select Amount
    from IntelilinkValues
)
ELSE NULL END
```

...it still won't work.

But this might work:

```
WITH IntelilinkValues (
    Amount,
    Frequency,
    Periods
)
AS (
SELECT 
    LBD.Amount,
    LBD.Payment_Frequency,
    LBD.No_of_Periods
FROM _SYS_BIC.LeasingRebooksDetails LBD 
WHERE LBD.Contract_Number='D003498006'
)
select Amount
into #ilv
from IntelilinkValues

select ss.somestuff, 
CASE 
WHEN SAPStreams.Stream_Type = 'INTELILINK' THEN (
    select Amount
    from #ilv
)
ELSE NULL END,
sot.someotherstuff

from SAPStreams ss
  inner join someothertable sot on sot.id = ss.id

where somecondition = 'true'

drop table #ilv
```

Answer (score 0):

I don'r have expierence in Cognos DB, but such query is inappropriate in Standart SQL style, because you try to return THREE FIELDS (Amount, Payment_Frequency, No_of_Periods) as a ONE FIELD (TestWITH) !!!

Comment: yeah, you're right - i didn't have that in there originally but thought maybe it was not liking the CASE because it wasn't assigning a field name.  Sorry, will edit.

Comment: Second: `CASE` operator uses only inside a `SELECT` clause. If you want to return set i sdependence of logical expression reslult then you should to use IF () BEGIN ... END
Third: what is the `SAPStreams.Stream_Type`? you call field of the table without `FROM` operator? You should to read SQL basics
`IF ( (SELECT Stream_Type FROM SAPStreams ORDER BY (...) OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH 1 NEXT ROW ONLY ) = 'INTELILINK' BEGIN <query> END`

Comment: I'm aware that CASE operators work only inside a select statement and that is where it is.  This is a huge query and the portion I provided is the only portion relevant to the discussion so I excluded the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Change the SQL syntax to Pass-Through

Comment: Please add a detailed explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Just change the SQL Syntax **from native to Direct**
and all will be okay !
It's

Comment: Your answer seems to come to an abrupt, unexpected end. Did you forget to add something?